# VirtualFileResult file not found when file exists

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, filenotfoundexception

Maybe I'm not understanding what a VirtualFileResult is, but I'm not sure why it's throwing a FileNotFoundException when the file exists. Here's the code:

```
if (System.IO.File.Exists(fileName))
{
    FileInfo info = new FileInfo(fileName);

    return File(fileName, FileUtility.GetContentType(fileName), info.Name);
}
```

(Edit: `FileUtility.GetContentType` (correctly) returns the Mime type of the file, which in my case is `"application/pdf"`.)

Here's the exception I get: (I removed the file path)

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file: [file path removed]
File name: '[file path removed]'
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.VirtualFileResult.<WriteFileAsync>d__11.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Controllers.FilterActionInvoker.<InvokeResultAsync>d__56.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Controllers.FilterActionInvoker.<InvokeResultFilterAsync>d__55.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Controllers.FilterActionInvoker.<InvokeAllResultFiltersAsync>d__54.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Controllers.FilterActionInvoker.<InvokeResourceFilterAsync>d__49.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Controllers.FilterActionInvoker.<InvokeAsync>d__44.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Infrastructure.MvcRouteHandler.<RouteAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Routing.Template.TemplateRoute.<RouteAsync>d__27.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Routing.RouteCollection.<RouteAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Builder.RouterMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler.IISPlatformHandlerMiddleware.<Invoke>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.StatusCodePagesMiddleware.<Invoke>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.<Invoke>d__7.MoveNext()
```

It's seemingly bugging out even though an explicit check was done for whether the file exists or not. I can also manually confirm the file exists.

Maybe I'm not understanding what a VirtualFileResult is (File method returns this). On the documentation [here](http://docs.asp.net/projects/api/en/latest/autoapi/Microsoft/AspNet/Mvc/VirtualFileResult/) it doesn't really describe what it is.

I'm using ASP.NET 5 RC1.

Answer (score 15):

The method you're looking for is [`PhysicalFile()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.physicalfile?view=aspnetcore-2.1):

```
return PhysicalFile(fileName, FileUtility.GetContentType(fileName), info.Name);
```

Beware, don't use a caller-supplied path with this.

Comment: could you explain on your caller-supplied path?

Answer (score 6):

The `VirtualFileResult` class needs the virtual path to the file in its constructor.
This means you need to provide the path relative to the `wwwroot` folder because it use HostingEnvironment's `WebRootFileProvider`.

```
    private IFileProvider GetFileProvider(IServiceProvider requestServices)
    {
        if (FileProvider != null)
        {
            return FileProvider;
        }

        var hostingEnvironment = requestServices.GetService<IHostingEnvironment>();
        FileProvider = hostingEnvironment.WebRootFileProvider;

        return FileProvider;
    }
}
```

Check the code on [github](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/VirtualFileResult.cs)

Answer (score 3):

No luck with File("index.html") or File("~/index.html"), Virtualfileresult throws NotFound.

My solution was to use Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerBase
method File(Stream fileStream...) :

```
public virtual FileStreamResult File(Stream fileStream, 
       string contentType, string fileDownloadName);
```

Index controller sample:

```
 using System.IO;
 using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
 using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

 public class IndexController : Controller
 {
    ILoggerFactory Logger;

    public IndexController(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        Logger = loggerFactory;
    }

    static string sep = Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString();

    [HttpGet("/index")]
    [HttpGet("/")]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var log = Logger.CreateLogger("trace");

        var path = $"{Startup.RootPath}{sep}index.html";
        log.LogWarning(path);
        Stream fileStream  = new System.IO.FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);

        return File(fileStream, "text/html");
    }
}

// AspnetCore version 1.1.1 :
// <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
// <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.1.1" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Your VirtualFileResult must be a relative path from the **application's wwwroot**.

```
return File("~/foo.js","text/javascript")
```

is going to point to wwwroot/foo.js